# Weird Tabbar animation when pop UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I face a weird behavior when poping UIViewCotnroller.

[image]

I notice it occurs for me on Whatsapp on my iOS12 too (but not frequently).

Comment: did resolved the problem? i'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I should have added the answer once I found it, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer is that it's an issue in iOS 8/9/10/11 and 12 and also occured in whatsapp.
The answer I found is to set the Translucent to false.

```
[self.tabBar setTranslucent:false];
```

of Swift

```
self.tabBar.translucent = false
```